# Portacle Emacs C-c C-c stopped working

Tags: debugging

I am a beginner Lisp programmer and new to Emacs. I work on Portacle. I must have done something because when I press `C-c C-c` to compile a function in a buffer I get: `C-c C-c is undefined`. This worked until about an hour before. I restarted Portacle a few times but it's the same all the time.

Here is the content of the message buffer:

```
Loading portacle...
Loading iso-transl...done
ad-handle-definition: ‘er/expand-region’ got redefined
Loading g:/Lisp/Portacle/portacle/config/user.el (source)...done
Loading portacle...done
Starting new Ispell process G:/Lisp/Portacle/portacle/win/bin/hunspell.exe with en_GB dictionary...
For information about GNU Emacs and the GNU system, type C-h C-a.
Polling "c:/Users/frmau/AppData/Local/Temp/slime.12988" .. 1 (Abort with ‘M-x slime-abort-connection’.)
Loading g:/Lisp/Portacle/portacle/config/.frame.el (source)...done
Polling "c:/Users/frmau/AppData/Local/Temp/slime.12988" .. 2 (Abort with ‘M-x slime-abort-connection’.)
Connecting to Swank on port 49981..
Connected. Are we consing yet?
Mark set
File mode specification error: (user-error Unmatched bracket or quote)
mwheel-scroll: Beginning of buffer [3 times]
C-c C-c is undefined
mwheel-scroll: Beginning of buffer [7 times]
C-c C-c is undefined
```

I work on Windows. I can't do any work until this is resolved.

Comment: Do you see the same problem if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: Please provide a step-by-step recipe to reproduce the problem, starting from `emacs -Q`. So far, it's not even clear which buffer is current when you try `C-c C-c`.

Comment: Whats emacs -q? I start Emacs by starting the Partacle exe. I just start Portacle, load a .lisp file, put my cursor at the end of a function definition in the file and press C-c C-c

Comment: Use the executable `runemacs -Q` to start Emacs, preventing loading of your init file. Then bisect your init file to find the culprit. You can use `M-x comment-region` to comment out a region of the code (with `C-u` it uncomments). Comment out 1/2, then 3/4, 7/8,... to load only the part of your init file that's relevant. Otherwise, you can hope that someone here will use the Portacle package and debug for you.

Comment: When this last happened I just seem to have solved itself when I started my computer the next day. But  now this has happened again, so I tried to follow the suggestion above, found the runemacs.exe file and opened a command prompt and typed runemacs -Q. A window with a single buffer came up and now I dont't know how to continue. I have looked previously for a config file but could not find one. There is a User.el file but that only seems to have my name and email address in it.

Comment: I just opened Portacle again and loaded a different file. and in this file C-c C-c worked as expected! I loaded up the file I was working on and again C-c C-c came up as undefined! How could that be?

Answer (score 1):

At least in my case, when I encountered the same problem, my inferior lisp process hadn't started for whatever reason. By left-clicking 'lisp' at the bottom right of the buffer, it gave me the option to 'Run inferior lisp process' (I'm sure there are many ways to do this).

This restored lisp editing commands such as C-c C-c.